# Separable Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the Initial value problem

$\displaystyle y' = \frac{ty(4-y)}{1+t}$

y(0)=yo>0

(A.) determine how the solution behaves as $t \rightarrow \infty$

For this I got:

$\displaystyle \frac{y}{y-4} = \left(\frac{C e^t}{1+t}\right)^4$

and so I got as $t \rightarrow \infty$, $y \rightarrow 4$.

(B.) If $y_0=2$, find the time $T$ at which the solution first reaches the value $3.99$

(C.) Find the range of initial values for which the solution lies in the interval $3.99<y<4.01$ by the time $t=2$.

I am unsure how to do part (B)

Comment: still something missing or wrong.

Comment: i added what was missing. I forgot to include that y(0)=yo>0

Comment: @Amzoti no I meant y. I just changed it

Comment: From $\frac y{y-4} = ( \frac{Ce^t}{1+t} )^4$ and $y(0)=2$, you can find the value of $C$. That will enable you to solve (B). A similar method will allow you solve (C).

Comment: It is worth noting that you should have $$\frac{y}{4-y}=\left(\frac{Ce^t}{1+t}\right)^4,$$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: Please fill in the details.

- For part a., after separation and integration, we have:

$$\dfrac{1}{4} \ln(4 - y) + \dfrac{1}{4} \ln(y) = t - \ln(t+1) + c $$

We can simplify this to solve for $y(t)$ as:

$$\dfrac{y}{4-y} = e^{4(t -\ln(t+1) + c)} = \dfrac{ce^{4 t}}{(t+1)^4}$$

Solving for $y(t)$ yields:

$$y(t) = \dfrac{4ce^{4t}}{ce^{4t} + (t+1)^4}$$

As $t \rightarrow \infty$, $y(t) = 4$.

- For part b., we have $y(0) = 2$, so $y(0) = \dfrac{4c}{c+1} = 2 \rightarrow c = 1$, hence:

$$y(t) = \dfrac{4 e^{4 t}}{(t+1)^4+e^{4 t}}$$

Now, you want to find $T$ where $y(T) = 3.99$. Here is a plot from WA:

[image]

What methods have you learned to find that $t$ (there are two negative roots and one positive root)?

**Spoiler**

> $$t = -1.07627, -0.90993, ~\mbox{or}~2.84367$$

You know how to do part c., and it is similar to part b.

Comment: can you show me how use simplified part (a) i understand the 4e^4t but not how you got the denominator

Comment: i believe I am missing something when doing B. When I plug  T into y(t) and set it equal to 2, i am not getting the correct answer. While working through the problem I arrive to ln(4e^4t)=ln(3.99e^4t)+(3.99e^e4t)+ln((3.99+3.99T)^4). Next I get, ln(4)+4T=ln(3.99)+4T+ln((3.99+3.99T)^4). Still simplifying I arrive at -.64 when the answer is 2.8436. Do you see the error I am making?